# Response 422: missing field though it is in body

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to call the inbenta auth api from my alexa skill:

```js
function authPOST(apikey, domain_key) {
    var body = {
            "domain_key": domain_key
        };
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var token = "";
    xhr.open("POST", "https://api.inbenta.io/v1/auth", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-inbenta-key", apikey);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {       
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).accessToken);
            token = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).accessToken;
            token = JSON.stringify(token);
            return token;
        }else{
            console.log(xhr);
    }};
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

Currently i am receiving the error within the response body:

```js
{"error":{"code":422,"message":"Secret or domain_key field is required"}}
```

though the domain key is part of the body, like required in the [auth documentation](https://developers.inbenta.io/general/authorization/auth-api-overview)
[documentation body structure](https://developers.inbenta.io/general/authorization/api-routes)

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Could you link the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, link is now in the post!